# awk Regular Expression (REGEX) get phone number from file

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk

The following is what I have written that would allow me to display only the phone numbers
in the file. I have posted the sample data below as well.

As I understand (read from left to right):
Using awk command delimited by "," if the first char is an Int and then an int preceded by [-,:*] and then an int preceded by [-,:*]. Show the 3rd column.

I used "www.regexpal.com" to validate my expression. I want to learn more and an explanation would be great not just the answer.

GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
awk -F "," '/^(\d)+([-,:*]\d+)+([-,:*]\d+)*$/ {print $3}' bashuser.csv

bashuser.csv
Jordon,New York,630-150,7234
Jaremy,New York,630-250-7768
Jordon,New York,630*150*7745
Jaremy,New York,630-150-7432
Jordon,New York,630-230,7790

Expected Output:
6301507234
6302507768
....
```

Comment: `\d` is **PCRE**, try `[0-9]+` or `[[:digit:]]+`

Comment: int or integer is generally a primitive data type.  This means that their size is limited.
Regex's `\d` refers to a digit. Which is a character of values between '0' and '9'

Comment: Lose the first `^`

Comment: Thanks for the information everyone. I added an expected output to see how you would go about solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just remove all non int

```sh
awk '{gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/, "")}1' file.csv
```

- `gsub` remove all match
- `[^[:digit:]]` the `^` everything but what is next to it, which is an int `[[:digit:]]`, if you remove the `^` the reverse will happen.
- `""` means remove or delete in awk inside the `gsub` statement.
- `1` means print all, a shortcut for `print`

In `sed`

```
sed 's/[^[:digit:]]*//g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your desired output always appears to start on field #3, you can simplify your regrex considerably using the following:

`awk -F '[*,-]' '{print $3$4$5}'`

#### Proof of concept

```
$ awk -F '[*,-]' '{print $3$4$5}' < ./bashuser.csv
6301507234
6302507768
6301507745
6301507432
6302307790
```

#### Explanation

- `-F '[*,-]'`: Use a character class to set the field separators to `*` OR `,` OR `-`.
- `print $3$4$5`: Concatenate the 3rd through 5th fields.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is not very suitable because the comma occurs not only as a separator of records, better results will give `sed`:

```
sed 's/[^,]\+,[^,]\+,//;s/[^0-9]//g;' bashuser.csv
```

- first part `s/[^,]\+,[^,]\+,//` removes first two records
- second part `//;s/[^0-9]//g` removes all remaining non-numeric characters